# How to get files in folder on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to get list of files in folder on Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 2):

```
   IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
   if(file.GetDirectoryNames().Contains("Personal"))
        {


            string directory = "Personal/";
            string[] filenames = file.GetFileNames(directory);
            List<FileData> files = new List<FileData>();
            foreach(string filename in filenames)
            {
                FileData f = new FileData();
                f.filename = filename;
                files.Add(f);

            }

            lstFiles.ItemsSource = files;
        }
```

This is just a code snippet retrieving files from a directory named Personal

Answer (score 1):

in Windows Phone 8 you should use the StorageFile and StorageFolder API:
[Quickstart: Working with files and folders in Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)